# getting xpath along with attributes names and values

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

take this xml file as an example:-

```
  <xyz version="1.0">
     <lives>
      <life key="1">
        <section name="Application123">
        <disclosure type="alcohol">
  <disclosure type="build">
    <internal>
  <height> data </height>
  <weight>data</weight>
  </internal>
  </disclosure>
  <disclosure type="drug">
  <disclosure type="tobacco">
  </section>
  </life>
  </lives>
  </xyz>
```

I want a query which gives me the path along with the attribute names and attribute values.
Suppose, I query for "build", then I want all  the paths  as follows:-

```
xyz/lives/life[key="1"]/section[name="Application123"]/disclosure[type="build"]/internal/height
```

I am able to get the paths using (working in xquery)

```
declare function local:path-to-node( $nodes as node()* )  as xs:string* {
                         $nodes/string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/name(.), ''/'')
```

as following:

```
xyz/lives/life/section/disclosure/internal/height
```

But I requires the attributes names and their values included as well.
Any suggestions friends?

Answer (score 0):

In a XPath, attributes need a `@` before them.

```
xyz/lives/life[@key='1']/section[@name='Application123']/disclosure[@type='build']/internal/height
```